# Getting error trying to submit data using JQuery ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

When I try to run the following JQuery ajax, I get an error saying that a parameter is missing and it will not send the data.  I can't find any syntax errors.  What am I doing wrong?

Here is the javascript with the JQuery ajax code:

```
function submitAction(actionname) {     

    if (actionname == "illustrationgenerate.htm") {

        var thisForm = document.getElementById("illustrationTypeForm");
        var fd = new FormData(thisForm);
        $.ajax({
            url: "illustrationgenerate.htm",
            type: "POST",
            data: fd,
            datatype: "xml",
            cache: false,
            success: function (result, status, xhr) {
                document.getElementById('errorMessage0').value="Success";
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                alert(xhr.status);
                alert(request.responseText);
            }                           
        });

    } else {
        document.forms[0].action = actionname;
        document.forms[0].method = "POST";
        document.forms[0].target = '';
        document.forms[0].submit();
    }
}
```

Comment: Where does this error appear, and where do you call this function? Is that parameter given?

Comment: It's `dataType`, isn't it? With a big T. Or perhaps it doesn't matter.

Comment: What is the exact error?

Answer (score 0):

Why not use jQuery native form encoder?

```
 $.ajax({
            ...
            data: $('#illustrationTypeForm').serializeArray(),
            ...

        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

Here is the javascript with the JQuery ajax code:

```
function submitAction(actionname) {     

    if (actionname == "illustrationgenerate.htm") {

        var thisForm = document.getElementById("illustrationTypeForm");
        var fd = new FormData(thisForm);
        $.ajax({
            url: "illustrationgenerate.htm",
            type: "POST",
            data: $('#illustrationTypeForm').serializeArray(),
            datatype: "xml",
            cache: false,
            success: function (result, status, xhr) {
                document.getElementById('errorMessage0').value="Success";
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                alert(xhr.status);
                alert(request.responseText);
            }                           
        });

    } else {
        document.forms[0].action = actionname;
        document.forms[0].method = "POST";
        document.forms[0].target = '';
        document.forms[0].submit();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To make ajax request using jQuery a type 'POST' you can do this by following code :

```
$.ajax({
    url: "test.php",
    type: "post",
    data: values ,
    success: function (response) {
       // you will get response from your php page (what you echo or print)                 
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
       console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
    }
});
```